# Python GDAL package does not handle rotated raster images correctly

Tags: python, gdal

I'm using the Python GDAL package to convert raster images between
various formats: ENVI, GeoTIFF, ERDAS Imagine, PCI Geomatics and others.
My imagery is UTM,  WGS-84 and path-oriented, i.e., rotated away from
north-up. I find that, after conversion with GDAL, the rotation is
always lost and the images are incorrectly oriented north-up. I'm using
the CreateCopy method in Python to do the conversion, e.g.,

newDataset = driver.CreateCopy(new.name, oldDataset)

Would appreciate any advice. Thanks,

Mort

Comment: where can i find an example raster file which is rotated?  I want to play with it.

Comment: Here are two ASTER images in ENVI format which are rotated -8.865 from north up:http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B7IDSHlM4SgEODYxMzQ0MTktYzA1Ni00OTIzLWFjMDUtZjQ5ZWZkZDZkNmVj&hl=en

Comment: If you prefer another format, let me know.

Comment: Mort, thanks, i got those two data set.

Comment: Just one observation, I opened it with ESRI ArcMap.  It ignores rotation, although i see the number for rotation in the .hdr file. The program acknowledged that coordinates for origin.  let me play with gdal next

Comment: `gdalinfo` on the file ignores the `rotation` attribute.  As `gdalinfo` does nothing on data and just describe what the data is, i guess this gdal also is another GIS system (in addition to ESRI/Arc) which does not implement rotation feature.  I guess ITT/ENVI's program should acknowledge `ratation` for sure, as they defined it.  What other program do you intend to use after file conversion?  Can you let that program do do file format change (or the ENVI itself)?

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. I have a Python app on Google Appengine that accepts various formats using GDAL and does some image analysis (principal components, change detection, etc.) I want the correct georeferencing (with rotation) to be able to project the image footprints onto a world map. See http://ms-image-analysis.appspot.com/static/index.html